# How do I properly wire a 0-10v LED dimmer switch?

Tags: wiring, led, dimmer-switch

I recently switched out my old fluorescent shop lights for new LED strip lights. This was super easy as the hot / neutral : ground were all cut and paste electrical work. These lights are controlled by a switch at the door. It’s a standard hot only wiring which is ok. Id like to be able to dim these lights so I picked up a dimmer switch but I’m confused what to do with the purple / grey wires coming from the LED “ballast” (for lack of a better term)

One article I read got me on the track to run thermostat or similar wire out of each LED fixture then down into the switch but then how do I wire the switch? Pigtail the hot in : the Tatar wire matched to purple / grey out?

Comment: If you just grabbed any random "dimmer switch" then no wonder you are confused.  0-10V dimming is a special case which requires special wiring. Follow the instructions on the lights and the 0-10V rated dimmer.  It's a commercial system so prices are high.

Comment: What make/model of 0-10V dimmer control are you using?

Comment: What is "the Tatar wire"?

Comment: With the rise of LEDs, residential stuff now can use the 0-10v dimming as well. NM-B-PCS Duo Cable is actually made for quickly putting up both the power and control lines at the same time.